# JSON to CSV Conversion in Python

Tags: python, json, csv

There're lots of questions regarding JSON to CSV Conversion in Python , but unfortunately couldn't solve my problem.

I've this simple simple JSON Data which is in a file and looks like this after loading.

**Raw data in single line [I've structured this to understand better]:**

```
{
    "t_id":"80740185.1558980000000.120184.121164",
    "s_id":"80740185",
    "pt_slot":"null:null",
    "ch_id":1,"o_id":121164,"c_id":120184,
    "msg_type":1,
    "amd":"{
                \"msg\":\" some Bengali text\",
                \"mask\":\"1GB_OFFER\",
                \"ec\":\"1\",
                \"time-out\":\"0\",
                \"validity\":\"30052019 000000\"
           }",
    "time":1558960217731,
    "dlr":"1",
    "msisdn":"xxxxx",
    "entity":1
}
```

**After loading to JSON formated data looks like below **

```
{
    u't_id': u'80740185.1558980000000.120184.121164', 
    u'c_id': 120184, 
    u'msg_type': 1, 
    u'dlr': u'1', 
    u'msisdn': u'xxxxxxxx', 
    u'amd': u'{
                "msg":" \u0986\u099c \u09b0\u09be\u09a4 \u09e7\u09e8\u099f\u09be\u09b0 \u09ae\u09a7\u09cd\u09af\u09c7 *21291*609# \u09a1\u09be\u09df\u09be\u09b2\u09c7 \u0995\u09bf\u09a8\u09c1\u09a8 \u09e7\u099c\u09bf\u09ac\u09bf \u09ef\u099f\u09be\u0995\u09be\u09a4\u09c7 (\u09e9\u09a6\u09bf\u09a8)",
                "mask":"1GB_OFFER",
                "ec":"1",
                "time-out":"0",
                "validity":"30052019 000000"
               }', 
    u'entity': 1, 
    u's_id': u'80740185', 
    u'ch_id': 1, 
    u'time': 1558960217731, 
    u'pt_slot': u'null:null', 
    u'o_id': 121164
}
```

I've above very simple JSON Data which I'm trying to convert to CSV data. But getting below error.

**Here is my code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import csv

def write_sms_dat_to_csv_file():
    f = csv.writer(open('csv_data.txt','wb+'),delimiter = '|')
    with open('test.dat') as fh:
            data = json.load(fh)

    for dt in data:
            f.writerow([dt['c_id'],dt['msisdn'],dt["amd"]["mask"]])

if __name__=="__main__":
    write_sms_dat_to_csv_file()
```

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./sms_data_read.py", line 16, in <module>
write_sms_dat_to_csv_file()
File "./sms_data_read.py", line 13, in write_sms_dat_to_csv_file
f.writerow([dt['c_id'],dt['msisdn'],dt['amd']['mask']])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Removing for loops with below statement gives same error:

```
f.writerow([data['c_id'],data['msisdn'],data['amd']["mask"]])
```

Comment: Is your `test.dat` a single json record? i.e. a single dictionary? Because if so the issue is that `for dt in data` iterates over the keys in that dict, and the string keys are only indexed by ints

Comment: The JSON encoding isn't correct. `amd` has ended up as a string

Comment: `amd` is holding a string, and you're trying to index that long string by `["mask"]`

Comment: I don't have 2.7 handy, but does `import ast` and then `f.writerow([dt['c_id'],dt['msisdn'],ast.literal_eval(dt['amd'])['mask']])` work?

Comment: why are you doing     `for dt in data:` just do `data["c_id"]` directly

Comment: Sorry .. I tried without for loop as well as there is only one row of data. Also given raw data. Kindly take a look

Comment: @roganjosh your solution worked without loop. Previously i tried with loop thats why it diddn't work. Could you please explain a bit? Thanks a lot btw.

Comment: If this is an API then they are serializing their data incorrectly according to JSON. `u'amd': u'{`, ignore the `u` for unicode, you can see that the dictionary stored against the `'amd'` key is actually a string (`'{` instead of `{` is the giveaway). `ast.literal_eval` takes that string and evaluates the content as a dictionary, so that you can now access by key. I'm not too hot on string encodings so it's possible that Python 3 would avoid this; doubtful but you should switch ASAP anyway since Python 2 will be deprecated shortly

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is that the dictionary you're trying to access through key 'amd' is actually a string. You can convert it to an actual dictionary by importing ast

```
import ast

sub_dict = ast.literal_eval(dt['amd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is a bit odd about your source JSON encoding, but if the structure is consistent with what you've provided, then you just need to parse the value in `dt['amd']` as well:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 27 2018, 07:35:06) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> json_string = '''
... [
...     {
...         "t_id": "80740185.1558980000000.120184.121164",
...         "s_id": "80740185",
...         "pt_slot": "null:null",
...         "ch_id": 1,
...         "o_id": 121164,
...         "c_id": 120184,
...         "msg_type": 1,
...         "amd": "{\\"msg\\": \\" some Bengali text\\", \\"mask\\": \\"1GB_OFFER\\", \\"ec\\": \\"1\\", \\"time-out\\": \\"0\\", \\"validity\\": \\"30052019 000000\\"}",
...         "time": 1558960217731,
...         "dlr": "1",
...         "msisdn": "xxxxx",
...         "entity": 1
...     }
... ]
... '''
>>> json_data = json.loads(json_string)
>>> for row in json_data:
...     row['amd'] = json.loads(row['amd'])
...     # Write row to CSV
... 
>>> json_data
[{'amd': {'ec': '1',
          'mask': '1GB_OFFER',
          'msg': ' some Bengali text',
          'time-out': '0',
          'validity': '30052019 000000'},
  'c_id': 120184,
  'ch_id': 1,
  'dlr': '1',
  'entity': 1,
  'msg_type': 1,
  'msisdn': 'xxxxx',
  'o_id': 121164,
  'pt_slot': 'null:null',
  's_id': '80740185',
  't_id': '80740185.1558980000000.120184.121164',
  'time': 1558960217731}]
```

Edited to provide full working example.

Comment: loading in for loop doesnt work as well ... same error pops up

Comment: Could you provide the value of your `dt` variable at the time of the error (i.e., provide the offending row)?

Comment: This would not work because `dt` takes on the keys of the dictionary `data`.

Comment: yes for loop wont work. when problem is popping up dt holds only "t_id".

Comment: Updated to provide a better description of what I was suggesting. I think the actual data is in a list (per "this is only one row"), so the iteration is over a list and not over a dict.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the loop. `json.load` returns a dictionary, and iterating over a dictionary with a `for...in` loop iterates over the *keys*. You are treating `dt` as a dictionary in the body of the loop, but it is actually a string—a key in the dictionary `data`. It also looks like something about the raw JSON data is causing `json.load` to not parse the value mapped to by `amd` as a JSON object, so `data["amd"]` is a string rather than a dictionary. You can get around this by parsing this string separately. Putting both of these things together, you should be able to replace the loop with

```
amd = json.load(data["amd"])
f.writerow([data['c_id'],data['msisdn'],amd["mask"]])
```

to get the result you're looking for.

Comment: I've tried this... it still doesn't work. edited question. Kindly check.

Comment: @Leon I gave you a suggestion in the comments that you haven't replied to

Comment: @roganjosh .. trying... give me 10 minutes.